How to copy a column if adjacent column does not contain a particular value to another column on the same sheet with Google Apps Script
I would like to copy values from D6:D to H6:H if the corresponding row in E6:E does not contain the value "Out".
Here is a screenshot of my desired results:



























































Michael Jordan



Michael Jordan





Babe Ruth



Babe Ruth





Joe Montana
Out








Wayne Gretzky



Wayne Gretzky





Lance Armstrong



Lance Armstrong





Roger Federer
Out








Lionel Messi



Lionel Messi



Here is the script that I have tried:
function copyAllPresent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base");
  const valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange(6,4,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const rangeToPaste = sheet.getRange(6,8,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  valuesToCopy.forEach(r => {
    if(r[4] != "Out") {
      rangeToPaste.setValues(valuesToCopy);
    }
  })
}

This just copies the entire range(D6:D) to H6:H regardless of the value in E6:E.

In your current script, at rangeToPaste.setValues(valuesToCopy);, the values valuesToCopy are put into column "H". By this, all values are put into column "H". When your script is modified, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?
function copyAllPresent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base");
  
  // Retrieve values from columns "D" and "E".
  const valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange(6, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  // Create a new array.
  const values = valuesToCopy.map(([d, e]) => [e != "Out" ? d : null]);

  // Put the array to column "H".
  sheet.getRange(6, 8, values.length).setValues(values);
}

As an additional modification, from but did not know how to created the new array., when const values = valuesToCopy.map(([d, e]) => [e != "Out" ? d : null]); is created by a for loop, it becomes as follows. I thought that this might help understanding to create a new array. In this modification, the same result with the above script is obtained.
function copyAllPresent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base");
  
  // Retrieve values from columns "D" and "E".
  const valuesToCopy = sheet.getRange(6, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  // Create a new array.
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < valuesToCopy.length; i++) {
    if (valuesToCopy[i][1] != "Out") {
      values.push([valuesToCopy[i][0]]);
    } else {
      values.push([null]);
    }
  }

  // Put the array to column "H".
  sheet.getRange(6, 8, values.length).setValues(values);
}


Less than ten minutes on here and an answer to something I puzzled over for an hour.  I knew what was wrong, but did not know how to created the new array.  Wonderful!  Thank you, Tainake!

@Codedabbler Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it. I thought that it might help understanding to create a new array.

Thank you.  Laying it out like that will be very helpful for future projects.

Is it possible to extend this further by adding another column to evalueate?  See subsequent question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78292917/how-to-copy-a-column-based-on-value-in-two-other-columns-to-another-column-on-th

@Codedabbler First, I apologize for my late reply. I confirmed your comment just now. When I saw your new question, I noticed that it had already been resolved. I'm glad about it.

That's OK.  But thank you.  You have been very helpful.
